Updating label text when font set with systemFont vs UIFont
When setting font in configureSpeedLabel and configureProgressLabel below, if I set font using UIFont speedLabel.font = UIFont(name: "TimesNewRomanPSMT", size: 24) then the progress track gets updated gradually as expected (Video: Track YES Updating), but when I set font using systemFont such as speedLabel.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 24, weight: .light) then progress track is not updating gradually (Video: Track NOT Updating).
Why is this happening? How to set using systemFont and keep the track updating as expected?
I believe it has to do with how variables speed and progress are getting updated with didSet but not sure how to pinpoint the issue.
import UIKit

class CircularProgressView: UIView {
    
    var progressLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    var trackLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    var speedLabel = UILabel()
    var progressLabel = UILabel()
    var uploadDownloadLabel = UILabel()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        configureSpeedLabel()
        configureProgressLabel()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
    }
    
    convenience init(withType type: String) {
        self.init()
        configureUploadDownloadLabel(withType: type)
    }
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        createCircularPath()
    }
    
    func configureUploadDownloadLabel(withType type: String) {
        uploadDownloadLabel = UILabel()
        uploadDownloadLabel.text = type
        uploadDownloadLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
//        uploadDownloadLabel.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 24, weight: .regular)
        uploadDownloadLabel.font = UIFont(name: "TimesNewRomanPSMT", size: 24)
        uploadDownloadLabel.textColor = UIColor.black
        uploadDownloadLabel.isOpaque = true
        self.addSubview(uploadDownloadLabel)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            uploadDownloadLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerXAnchor),
            uploadDownloadLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor, constant: -35)
        ])
    }
    
    var progressColor = UIColor.white {
        didSet {
            progressLayer.strokeColor = progressColor.cgColor
            print("didSet progressColor")
        }
    }
    
    var trackColor = UIColor.white {
        didSet {
            trackLayer.strokeColor = trackColor.cgColor
            print("didSet trackColor")
        }
    }
    
    var speed = 0 {
        didSet {
            speedLabel.text = String(speed) + " Mbps"
        }
    }
    
    var progress = 0.0 {
        didSet {
            progressLayer.strokeEnd = progress
            progressLabel.text = String(format: "%.0f", (progress*100).rounded()) + "%"
        }
    }
    
    fileprivate func configureSpeedLabel() {
        speedLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        speedLabel.text = String(speed) + " Mbps"
        speedLabel.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 24, weight: .light)
//        speedLabel.font = UIFont(name: "TimesNewRomanPSMT", size: 24)
        speedLabel.textColor = UIColor.black
        speedLabel.isOpaque = true
        self.addSubview(speedLabel)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            speedLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerXAnchor),
            speedLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerYAnchor)
        ])
    }
    
    fileprivate func configureProgressLabel() {
        progressLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        progressLabel.text = String(format: "%.0f", (progress*100).rounded()) + "%"
        progressLabel.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 24, weight: .thin)
//        progressLabel.font = UIFont(name: "TimesNewRomanPSMT", size: 24)
        progressLabel.textColor = UIColor.black
        progressLabel.isOpaque = true
        self.addSubview(progressLabel)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            progressLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerXAnchor),
            progressLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor, constant: 10)
        ])
    }
    fileprivate func createCircularPath() {
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        self.layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.width/2
        let path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: frame.width/2, y: frame.height/2), radius: (frame.width - 1.5)/2, startAngle: CGFloat(-0.5 * .pi), endAngle: CGFloat(1.5 * .pi), clockwise: true)
        trackLayer.path = path.cgPath
        trackLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        trackLayer.strokeColor = trackColor.cgColor
        trackLayer.opacity = 0.5
        trackLayer.lineWidth = 10.0
        trackLayer.strokeEnd = 1.0
        self.layer.addSublayer(trackLayer)

        progressLayer.path = path.cgPath
        progressLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        progressLayer.strokeColor = progressColor.cgColor
        progressLayer.lineWidth = 10.0
        progressLayer.strokeEnd = 0.0
        self.layer.addSublayer(progressLayer)
    }

}


The reason is that whenever the size of progressLabel changed, it will trigger the override func layoutSubviews(). At that point, the code recreated the circular path with the strokeEnd = 0.0. If the size of progressLabel size is keeping changing, the circular path will stuck at the beginning. That's what happens if using the .systemFont(ofSize: 24, weight: .thin).

Although I am calling configureSpeedLabel and configureProgressLabel only once so I would think that the systemFont would only be set once in the beginning. Why is it different than setting the label font with UIFont(name: ...

TimesNewRomanPSMT has fixed width numeric characters while .systemFont numeric characters are not fixed width characters. That's why with .systemFont updating the text of the label will cause the size of label change more often which in turn triggers the func layoutSubviews() than with TimesNewRomanPSMT

That's interesting. If I simply set the font with .systemFont(ofSize: 24, weight: .regular, width: .standard) then would it prevent the triggering or is it simply that because .standard is different between numeric and alphabetic chars then it would still trigger the layoutSubviews(). And is there a way for me to override the layoutSubviews() in order to prevent that change from occurring?

Also it's not clear to me why does it matter whether systemFont has fixed or not width for numeric chars since the layoutSubviews is actually repeatedly called due to changes in the progress. Meaning if it's being called anyways why would it suddenly for a reset of the progress? The progress is only initialized at 0.0 in the beginning and gets updated.

layoutSubviews will only be called if the size of view itself or any of its children views change. If the font has fixed width  numeric character, it will not call the layoutSubviews until it changes from one digit to two digits.

Whenever it creates the circular path, the code will set the progressLayer.strokeEnd to 0.0 which reset the progress circular path to 0.0 position. Also every time layoutSubviews is called, the code create one set of trackLayer and progressLayer and add to the view's layer which will end up with a lot of layers. Suggest to move the createCircularPath out of the layoutSubviews

That's great info. With regard to moving createCircularPath out of layoutSubview: when I move it to init it actually does not create the circular paths. I believe that is because the trackLayer and progressLayer properties are only created after the init.

After some manipulations moved the createCircularPath out of layoutSubviews and into init but now it appears very small: progress view very small image link
